Getting same Index # for duplicate numbers

Create a program, loopindex.py. Your program should:
Convert these string-type integers into integer-type.
For each of the numbers in the list, add its own index position.
Example 1 - If the argument is ['5', '5', '5'], the program should print:
[5, 6, 7]

Example 2 - If the argument is ['4', '11', '0', '0', '1'], the program should print:
[4, 12, 2, 3, 5]


Code:
import sys

loop_list = sys.argv[1:]

def loopindex(loop_list):
  index = []
  for i in loop_list:
    y = loop_list.index(i)
    x = int(i)
    index.append(x + y)
  print(index)
  
loopindex(loop_list)


I have tried the above and I get the indices that I need except for numbers that are duplicated in the string. How do I get it to recognize each number as its own index?
For example, when I run example 2 from above 4, 11, 0, 0, 1, my output is 4, 12 , 2, 2, 5. I want the output to be 4, 12, 2, 3, 5.

index() always finds the first occurrence of the value.  So it's finding the first 0 twice.  If you want to loop over a list and get the values and their list positions, use enumerate().

The list.index function will always return the index of the first match. Clearly if the elements in the list are not all unique, this poses a problem, so this is not a reasonable approach to this problem.
Instead just maintain the index as a variable which is incremented on each loop iteration.
def loopindex(loop_list):
  index = []
  i = 0
  for x in loop_list:
    index.append(int(x) + i)
    i += 1
  print(index)

Using enumerate this is more straightforward:
def loopindex(loop_list):
  index = []
  for i, x in enumerate(loop_list):
    index.append(int(x) + i)
  print(index)

Or, using a list comprehension:
def loopindex(loop_list):
  print([i + int(x) for i, x in enumerate(loop_list)])

A rather clumsy fix to your original approach would be to change each element of the list after finding it, but not adding to or subtracting from the list while iterating over it. There are corner cases that will break this.
>>> lst = [5, 5, 5]
>>> def loopindex(lst):
...     # Make a copy of lst so we don't modify the original
...     lst = lst[:]
...     index = []
...     for x in lst:
...         i = lst.index(x)
...         index.append(int(x) + i)
...         lst[i] = (x, i)
...     print(index)
...
>>> loopindex(lst)
[5, 6, 7]


Using i, j in enumerate(loop_list): instead of i in loop_list:, you'll have the expected result.
loop_list = ['5', '5', '6', '7']
for i, j in enumerate(loop_list):
    print(i, j)

[out]:
0 5
1 5
2 6
3 7

Then:
loop_list = ['5', '5', '6', '7']

def loopindex(loop_list):
  index = []
  for i, j in enumerate(loop_list):
    x = int(j)
    index.append(i + x)
  print(index)
  
loopindex(loop_list)

[out]: [5, 6, 8, 10]

